# Remove Forward Slash from html tags in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, slash

I want to use the find and replace feature in Dreamweaver to search for meta tags and link tags with /> in them and replace them with >.

For example:

```
<meta name=..... />
```

Replace with:

```
<meta name=.... >
```

I discovered that this helps me find them all: `<META[^>]*\/>`

but how do I replace them so that all the meta content is there EXCEPT the forward slash?

Comment: stop using dreamweaver it is so 2000, sublime text 2 or coda even notepad ++ is better than that...

Comment: looks like I have to use regex in notepad++ too. so thanks for nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for this:

```
<(META[^>]*)\/>
```

And replace with this:

```
<($1)>
```